# Generate documentation from step definition(java) and feature files using Cucumber and Gherkin

Tags: java, cucumber, jruby, gherkin, yard

I am using Cucumber, Gherkin and feature files in our automation project for testing purpose. This is a java project. So our step definition files are written in java using gherkin tags. I want to generate documentation (maybe in html) like [yard-cucumber](http://burtlo.github.io/yard-cucumber/requirements.html) from java and feature files. Yard-cucumber generates the documentation after  read/scan the feature and steps definition(written in ruby) files. I used the similar approach for java using jruby. But it is not scanning java files and giving error. 
Is there any tool/plugin to generate document after reading/scan feature and step definition files written in java? or any parser available in jruby with yard-cucumber to scan java files?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Cukedoctor](https://github.com/rmpestano/cukedoctor) might be what you're looking for. It uses the Cucumber JSON execution output to generate documentation.